# Trying to call a function inside preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$string = 'Hello [user=1]';

$bbc = array('/\[user=(.*?)\]/is');

$replace = array(user('textlink',$1));
$s = preg_replace($bbc , $replace, $string);
echo $s
```

How do I change `$1` in `preg_replace` with a function?

Comment: See [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to execute `user()` function on each match? As mentioned in comments, use the [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function.

```
<?php
$string = 'Hello [user=1]';
$s = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[user=(.*?)\]/is',
    function($m) {return user('textlink', $m[1]);},
    $string
);
echo $s;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a [`preg_replace_callback_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array.php):

```
$string = 'Hello [user=1]';

$bbc = array(
    '/\[user=(.*?)\]/is' => function ($m) {
            return user('textlink',$m[1]);
        });

$s = preg_replace_callback_array($bbc, $string);
echo $s;
```

See [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/n7erHh).

You may add up the patterns and callbacks to `$bbc`.